# Where does the thought 'we were not even fit to eat the crumbs from under your table' originate, in the Anglican communion service?

Tags: new-testament, apologetics, forgiveness

Does anyone know if there is a scripture reference for this, if not what is the thinking behind it?

Comment: Have you tried looking this up online? The answer can be found in Matthew 15:27.

Comment: Yes, but the confession of the Canaanite woman is a different confession. Her confession is not "I am not fit" or even " I have been unfit rather, " even the dogs eat the crumbs"

Comment: Jesus commends this as a statement of faith

Comment: I would imagine that it is a direct adaption. The encounter in Matthew 15 is very well known.

Comment: Maybe you should change your question to ask for an explanation of this encounter, and why Jesus calls the Caananite woman a "dog", and why she accepts the apparent insult?

Comment: Yes I know, but it would just be called out as subjective i think.

Comment: My own personal reasoning is that He doesn't think of any one nation as dogs but he was teasing her to bring out her faith, which is still way different to the inferences of the Anglican confession.

Comment: I think that an objective answer is possible, and one that is supported by most commentaries.

Comment: Ok I will post that question shortly

Comment: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/2837/23657.  Good  answers here

Answer (score 1):

We see at Luke 16: 19-21:

"There was a rich man who was dressed in purple and fine linen and who feasted sumptuously every day.   And at his gate lay a poor man named Lazarus, covered with sores,   who longed to satisfy his hunger with what fell from the rich man’s table; even the dogs would come and lick his sores."

There was presumably a custom among the rich, of cleaning one's  fingers between one course of meal and another  with some inferior kind of bread, which would then be discarded , as we do with tissue papers today . (I am sorry I am unable to quote any reference in support of the prevalence of such a custom at the time of Jesus.)